Usage of Not + nor/or?
I'm confused by when to use nor.
I know it follows neither in sentences like:

Neither he, nor I can help you.

And it can also be used like this ("instead" of neither?):

I don't know what to do. Nor/(Neither?) does anyone else.

But what's tripping me up is using it with not. For instance, is it correct to use it like this?

I don't have plans nor money.

If not, are there any other usages with not where you would use nor ("instead" of or)?

The correct answer is given at the duplicate, but it is not the most upvoted and selected one. 'I don't have [plans or money].' The scope of the negator includes both NPs ('plans' & 'money'). 'I don't have either [plans or money]', ie 'I don't have either plans or money', perhaps makes this clearer. //// Removing 'nor' to a separate clause validates by extracting it from the scope of the first negator: 'I don't have plans; neither/nor do I have money'.

I agree the duplicate asks about the same thing as my question. However, people don't seem to agree on what the answer is. Also I don't love the fact that if anyone stumbles onto my question will now be redirected to a place where the accepted answer doesn't even really answer the question. Your second comment here does a much better job of answering it than that accepted answer.

Rebecca Small's answer says essentially the same thing: 'In your example, or is correct because it is connecting two nouns and the negative is established by the not.'

Both "no" and "neither" are correct, but "neither" is used more often.

"I don't have plans nor money" would be better said as "I have neither plans nor money."

I don't have plans, nor (do I have) money. ("nor …" can be added as an afterthouht.)


Agreed with what you said but what I'm specifically interested in is whether that sentence in that particular form is correct or not: "I don't have plans nor money."? Or should I use "or" instead: "I don't have plans or money."?
